# Why doesn't wp_redirect cause header warning?

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

In the past when I used wp_redirect, I had to put the redirect in an action like init or I would get Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by.

I came across a case today where the redirect was just in single.php.

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying all single posts
 *
 * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#single-post
 *
 * @package Adele_Royce
 */

get_header();
?>
<?php if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) { 
     wp_redirect( 'https://example.com/login/');
 } else { ?>
<section class="blog-wrap">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-xl-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
    <main id="primary" class="site-main">

        <?php
        while ( have_posts() ) :
            the_post();

            get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_type() );

        endwhile; // End of the loop.
        ?>

    </main><!-- #main -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->
</div>
</div>
</div>
</section>
<?php } ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Why doesn't this cause the header warning?

Comment: Possibly the theme has `ob_start()` somewhere which buffers the output until it finishes processing, in which case it's possible to send headers after content

Answer (score 0):

As the [documentation of wp_direct](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_redirect/) says

> Note: wp_redirect() does not exit automatically, and should almost always be followed by a call to exit;

Change your code and exit after the redirect:

```
wp_redirect( 'https://example.com/login/');
exit;
```

If you don't exit, all the content is processed and one header will be sent by the echoing content and one by the redirect.

Comment: `
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
 exit; // Exit if accessed directly.
}

get_header();

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
 exit; // Exit if accessed directly.
}

wp_redirect( 'https://example.com/login/');
exit();
`

I put this as the top of page.php and it still redirects without the warning.